Connecting the GeoServer
I am deploying the GeoServer instance to my machine. My Java version is 11 and have set the JAVA_HOME to environment path. When running the startup. The localhost:8585 looks good, but I get 404 response when clicking the /geoserver. Could anyone give me a hint what will cause this error?


How did you install GeoServer? Normally I would look at port 8080

Do you get the same response with http://localhost:8585/geoserver?

I get the same response with http://localhost:8585/geoserver. It returns 404 and saying the reason is  "Not Found". I've checked the "start" config file in my geoserver directory. The HTTP port to listen on is "jetty.port=8585", and I ensure that this port is opening to listen in the firewall. Actually, localhost:8585 is accessible, shown as the image, but I am not sure what do I miss for the /geoserver

what does the log file say?
